# Induction proof that the number of edges of a complete graph with $x$ vertices is always $\frac{x^2-x}{2}$

Tags: graph-theory, induction

I am trying to prove that the number of edges of a complete graph with $x$ vertices is always $\frac{x^2-x}{2}$.

I'm having trouble figuring out this proof by induction.  I've only just started doing induction proofs and I'm not entirely sure where to begin.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{x(x-1)}{2}$? When $x=3$, $3^2-\frac{3}{2}$ is not an integer.

Comment: I've edited your post to include the question *in the body of the question*, and to format the title.  However, like Toby, I don't know if you meat $\frac{x^2-x}{2}$ or $x^2 - \frac{x}{2}$.  Please check my work and make appropriate adjustments.

Comment: The first one, I apologize.  I don't yet know how to format equations properly on this site.  Thank you!

Comment: @MrGameandWatch $\frac{x^2-x}{2}$ can be formatted as \$frac{x^2-x}{2}$. Here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (yes, it's quite messy).

Answer (score 3):

Guide:

- Consider base case: a singleton.
- Assume the result hold true for $x$ vertices.
- Think of how to construct a complete graph with $x+1$ vectices by adding a single node. Think of how many edges are needed to be added to the complte graph of $x$ vertices to form a complete graph of $x+1$ nodes. Use the induction hypothesis (number of edges of $x$ vertices plus the number of additional edges that are needed to include the additional node).

Comment: Right, so the number of edges needed be added to the complete graph of x+1 vertices would be ((x+1)^2) - (x+1) / 2?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the total number of edges in the complete graph with $x+1$ nodes? Perhaps working with particular example might help, let $x=2$, construct a complete graph with $2$ nodes, it is a line. Now, a third note appear, how many additional edge is needed to form a triangle?